# Как в SQLite быстро получить количество групп в таблице?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в SQLite быстро получить количество групп в таблице?
Или создать другую динамическую таблицу, где автоматически хранится экземпляр групп по одному?

Comment: а при чем тут sqlite? там какой-то другой язык, отличный от sql?

Comment: @Dmitry вы правы тема идёт о языке sql, написал sqlite это по привычке

Comment: вам должно помочь вот это https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-distinct.php

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо очень интересно, ознакомлюсь и скажут ответ

Comment: @Dmitry Вы очень правильно ответили, оказывается надо использовать DISTICT.
Но это медленно работает оказывается если в таблице 5-10 млн строк, имею в виду даже после индексирования. Нету ли другие способы или приёмы, чтобы даже при вставке элементов в таблицу отняло много времени, а при получение быстро показало результат.